c# Microsoft Semantic Kernel - RAG using local files
I am new to Semantic Kernel and would like to build an application using RAG (local file implementation). I know this is possible in OpenAI using "KernelMemoryBuilder" and "WithOpenAIDefaults" method. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
I have tried below implementations but they use OpenAI.
https://microsoft.github.io/kernel-memory/serverless
https://github.com/microsoft/kernel-memory
